# Should I use a text file or Database?

Tags: java, database

So I'm putting together an RSS parser which will process an RSS feed, filter it, and then download the matched items. Assume that the files being downloaded are legal torrent files.

Now I need to keep a record of the files that I have already downloaded, so they aren't done again.

I've already got it working with SQLite (create database if not exists, insert row if a select statement returns nothing), but the resulting jar file is 2.5MB+ (due to the sqlite libs).

I'm thinking that if I use a text file, I could cut down the jar file to a few hundred kilobytes.

I could keep a list of the names of files downloaded - one per line - and reading the whole file into memory, search if a file exists, etc.

The few questions that occur to me know:

- Say if 10 files are downloaded a day, would the text file method end
  up taking too much resources?
- Overall which one is faster

Anyway, what do you guys think? I could use some advice here, as I'm still new to programming and doing this as a hobby thing :)

Comment: +1 for the qualification that the torrents are legal despite having no relevance to the actual program. That made me smile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to keep track only of few informations (like name of the file), you can for sure use a simple text file.

Using a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read you should achieve good performance.

Comment: If it can be shrinked down to pairs of key and value, `java.util.Properties` will do the job with ease.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically DB (either relational or NoSQL is better. But if the distribution size is critical for you using file system can be preferable.

The only problem here is the performance of data access (either for write or for read). Probably think about the following approach. Do not use one single file. Use directory that contains several files instead. The file name will contain key (or keys) that allow access specific data just like key in map. In this case you will be able to access data relatively easily and fast.

Probably take a look on XStream. They have implementation of Map that is implemented as described above: stores entries on disk, each entry in separate file.

Comment: What issues will data access cause? I'll only be reading or writing at any particular time, not both.
- Pardon the late reply btw